# ORACLE DataBase: VIEW has nullable column after union two tables with non-nullable column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

In Oracle Database:

I need that the `PRODUCT_ID` column in view will be not-nullable.
The view is an `UNION` of two tables, that in each on the column `PRODUCT_ID` is not-nullable.
But for some reason in the view, this column is nullalbe.

syntax:

```
SELECT MAP_DATA.PRODUCT_ID, MAP_DATA.PRODUCT NAME
FROM (
    select PRODUCT_ID , PRODUCT_NAME
    FROM TABLE_1

    UNION 

    SELECT PRODUCT_ID , PRODUCT_NAME
    FROM TABLE_2
      ) MAP_DATA
```

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: Does `Select count(*) from table_2 where product_id is null` OR  `Select count(*) from table_1 where product_id is null` return something different than 0 ? Also, as far as I understand from your question - you think that the View column product_id, being nullable can actually become null at some point? Have in mind that the base tables` constraints do not translate to the view magically, as the view is only a "window" to the data.

Comment: No. in both of the tables the column is not-nullable

Comment: The view definition will reflect the actual (real) column definitions only for simple statements. You can't expect all constraints of the underlying columns to show up in the definition of the view

Comment: ok. but there is any way to defined this column as not-nullable? without this i cant get this column to the entity framework.

Comment: What is the precise problem with Entity Framework?

Comment: When trying to import the view to the EDMX file, the view not added becouse it didnt have a non-nullable column for primary key.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your view is not an updatable view. It's read-only, because of the underlying query is a UNION of two tables.

If you had a view like this

```
create or replace view view_2
    (PRODUCT_ID
    , PRODUCT_NAME)
as
SELECT MAP_DATA.PRODUCT_ID, MAP_DATA.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM  TABLE_2 MAP_DATA
with check option
/
```

Then a query on `all_tab_cols` for `'VIEW_2'` would show `nullable='N'`. This is because Oracle can directly map the columns in the view with the columns in the underlying table. It can't do that with the UNIONed query (because it's perfectly acceptable for the columns of one table to be nullable and the other mandatory).

With the simple view we can execute an insert statement directly against the view. But we can't do that with a view such as yours, for obvious reasons (which table should the new record go in?). To make the view updatable we need to write an INSTEAD OF trigger, in which we can enforce any business rules we need.

Oracle allows us to specify primary key and unique constraints on views (using the magic `RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE` clause,) but not NOT NULL (i.e check) constraints.

Note that the column remains nullable even if we define the view with a primary key like this:

```
create or replace view view_1
(PRODUCT_ID
, PRODUCT_NAME
, constraint v1_pk primary key (product_id) rely disable novalidate
)
as
SELECT MAP_DATA.PRODUCT_ID
       , MAP_DATA.PRODUCT_NAME

FROM (
    select PRODUCT_ID , PRODUCT_NAME
    FROM TABLE_1

    UNION 

    SELECT PRODUCT_ID , PRODUCT_NAME
    FROM TABLE_2
      ) MAP_DATA
 with check option
/
```